# How to download a file from Linux server in shell using Unix command

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to download a file to my local computer Windows 7 in my server in Shell using UNIX command.

Is there a way to do this?

I also have Ubuntu installed on my computer. Do I need to do another method for downloading a file from my server from shell?

I was wondering if this can be done without using GUI software.

Cheers

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "download...to" is either redundant or backwards.  If you just want to download a file use wget.  What is the source and destination?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at **scp**, which comes preinstalled with your Ubuntu installation, as part of `SSH`.

Knowing the path of the file you simply do:

```
scp suser@sip:/location/of/file .
```

scp will *copy* the file, and the . means copy to the current folder on your local machine, where
 
`suser` is your user on your `server`(!) and
`sip` is your `server's` IP.

If it's a folder you need `scp -r` instead of `scp` in the above.
If after the : you have a / like above, it's the location relative to the root `/` of the file system. If you omit the first `/` it's the location relative to your user's `home directory`.

It will ask you for the password for your user on the server.

Comment: This will work when copying files between Unix-like machines (provided you have ssh set up), but on Windows 7 this requires something like Cygwin (as Aditya Naidu points out).

Comment: Yes, but the user stated he was talking about a linux server and he mentioned he als had ubuntu installed on his local computer (or so I understand it). It is easier to do from ubuntu.

Comment: I added the information to install ssh/scp.

Comment: I believe ssh is preinstalled. You may need openssh-server on the linux server. pscp, which comes with putty would be a good client on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can install cygwin on your Windows machine and run sshd in cygwin. Then you can scp files either ways from either of the machines.